# Text widget overflow in row not clipping properly

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-text

I am building a widget in flutter and am attempting to display two text widgets in a row with spacing in between them so that each text widget is aligned at the end of the row. Sometimes these two text widgets are too large to occupy the row together, therefore I need to clip one widget to prevent overflow. I am trying to produce this effect using the "Spacer" package, however my output is not what is expected.

**Output**

[image: output]

**Expected**

[image: expected]

**Code**

*gridview*

```
Expanded(
    child: GridView.count(
  childAspectRatio: 100.w * 1.65 / 100.h,
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  controller: viewModel.controller
    ..addListener(() {
      viewModel.handleScrolling(
         viewModel.controller, viewModel.focusNode);
    }),
  children: <Widget>[
    for (final listing in viewModel.results) ...[
      ListingCard(
        listing: listing
    ],
  ],
)),
*this lives within a column*
```

*listingcard*

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Card(
    child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
                Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1.5.w),
                    child: Row(children: [
                      Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 1.5.w),
                          child: (listing.listingType == 'Percentage')
                              ? Text('${listing.price!.toInt()}% off',
                                  maxLines: 1,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 8.sp,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700))
                              : Text("\$ ${listing.price.toString()}",
                                  maxLines: 1,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 8.sp,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700))),
                      const Spacer(),
                      Text("${listing.brand}",
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          maxLines: 1,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 8.sp, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400))
                    ]))
            ],
    )))
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

**Attempts to fix:**

*Wrapping the 2nd Text Widget (brand) with Expanded & Flexible*

Both of these outputs are Identical. The issue being that the Spacer flexible space takes precedent over the wrapped text, producing a fixed gap, which I want to be dynamic.

[image: incorrect]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your brand text with `Expanded` widget and provide  `textAlign: TextAlign.right`

```dart
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1.5),
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Padding(.....),
      Expanded(
        child: Text(
            "{listing.ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssbrand}",
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            textAlign: TextAlign.right,
            maxLines: 1,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try remove spacer beetween these two widgets and set **mainAxisAlignment** in Row to get dynamic gap:

```
 Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: ...
);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your overflowing text with `Expanded`.

This tells Flutter that that `Text` widget will take as much space as possible, which implies that the ellipsis will take effect.

EDIT. I am unable to play around with it at the moment, but try it with `Flexible`, too, if possible, as this shouldn't force anything on the layout.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This is the solution on any related question I could find here on stackoverflow, however I had tried these earlier with no luck. I have edited my question to display the effect of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

check this is for row overflowed fixed

```
Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1.5),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                    child: Text("succefull",
                        maxLines: 1,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Flexible(
                    child: Text(
                        "succefuldfgdgjhhjkhkjhjkhkjshkjdsajkdhkjashdkjhakjfdhakjfhdjkasfjkhajksfbkjsbfl",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Row(
//                   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Flexible(
                        child: Text("\$ 343.45",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                            "{listing.sssssssdsfsdfsdfdsdfssdssdsadggjgjkjkgjkgjkgjkk222222222222222jhjkhjkhjkhjkhjhkjhjkhjkhkjhkjhkjhkjhkjhkjssjkhkhlkhllkjlkjklkljlkjlkjkljkl}",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```